# Extracting Directory String from Text

Tags: vb.net, string, logging

I have a program that I am making with visual basic 2010 that will pull logs of corrupted files and give the user the location of the corrupted file(s) to fix it. These logs are huge and vary depending on the amount of corruption.

I already have set in code to only pull the lines of text that are flagged as errors but, within these lines, there are directories that point to what file is corrupted. I need to know if there is any way to read these directories and put them into a `RichTextBox`. Here is an example of a line from a log file:

> oa = @0x238282b270->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[100]"\??\C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_3ware.inf.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10130.0_en-us_ca9e7cc7a071e60f"; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, iosb = @0x238282b250, as = (null), fa = 0,

And here is the part that I need to pull from it:

> C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_3ware.inf.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10130.0_en-us_ca9e7cc7a071e60f from this string

I'm pretty new to all of this, so bear with me please.

Comment: Are there any **rules** we can use to determine where the filename begins and ends?  For instance, can we **always** look for "\??\ at the beginning?  Will it **always** end with a double quote and a semi-colon ?  Will the file **always** be on "C:\"?  etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegEx provides great flexibility for this sort of thing, but you need to establish a known pattern that defines where the path begins and ends.  For instance, if it always is prefixed by `on:[100]"\??\` and always ends with `";`, then you could extract it with this RegEx pattern:

> on:[100]"\\?\?\(.*?)";

Here's what the pattern means:

- `on:\[100\]"\\\?\?\\` - Matches must begin with `on:[100]"\??\` exactly

  - The extra backslashes are necessary to escape all of the special characters which would otherwise have special meaning.  In this case, `[`, `]`, `\`, and `?` all have special meaning to RegEx, so they each need to be preceded a the backslash to escape them.
- `(.*?)` - Matches can contain any number of any characters between the preceding `on:[100]"\??\` and the following `";`.  The value of this portion of the input is captured as an unnamed group (i.e. group 1).

  - `(` - Begins a capturing group
  - `.` - Matches any character
  - `*` - Any number of times
  - `?` - Matches in a non-greedy fashion (i.e. only captures up through the first instance of whatever follows it in the pattern)
  - `)` - Ends the capturing group
- `";` - Matches must end with these two characters exactly

So, for instance:

```
Dim input As String = "oa = @0x238282b270->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[100]""\??\C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_3ware.inf.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10130.0_en-us_ca9e7cc7a071e60f""; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, iosb = @0x238282b250, as = (null), fa = 0,"
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(input, "on:\[100\]""\\\?\?\\(.*?)"";")
If m.Success Then
    Dim path As String = m.Groups(1).Value
End If
```

Or, if the input can contain multiple matches, you can loop through them like this:

```
For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(input, "on:\[100\]""\\\?\?\\(.*?)"";")
    Dim path As String = m.Groups(1).Value
Next
```

That's just an example.  Depending upon your needs, you could adjust the RegEx pattern as necessary.  RegEx is very flexible, so as long as there's some logical way to recognize where the path is in the string, it should be possible to find it with a RegEx pattern.  On a side note, since the pattern is, itself, just a string, it can be stored in a configuration setting outside of the code too, which is an added benefit.

Comment: Yes the directory will always be on the C: drive and the string will end with a quotation mark. this code looks promising and i will play around with it but "match" is not recognized. what do i need to import to get this command to work. sorry for my ignorance and thanks for yalls help.

Comment: It's declared in the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll` library, so you will need to reference that in your project references.  It's in the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace, so you'll either need to fully qualify it or add the `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` directive to the top of the code file where you use it.

Comment: this code worked great for that exact log but not for another. could you describe to me how to format properly a regex pattern so that i can edit it to be universal? thank you

Comment: I'd also recommend you to read the System-driveletter. On some guy's machine my code kept crashing until i looked right at the machine. He changed the Windows-Driveletter to D:\ ...  you can read the env-var for windir as a string and then change your regex  to whatever the user has fiddled it to.

Comment: It's hard to know how to fix the pattern without seeing a variety of entries.  I will however, add an explanation of what the parts of the pattern mean.

Comment: well i was able to use the code you provided me to extract the error log directory from any log i tested with. but the only issue is it will only output the first line that it finds. it will not output any of the other directories if the log contains them.

Comment: Well, there are two ways to handle that.  If you pre-filter to find only the lines that are errors, then you can loop through each error line and call RegEx on each one.  Alternatively, you could pass the entire log file to RegEx as input and use it's `Matches` method (instead of `Match`), which returns a list of all of the matches.  Then you would need to loop through all of the matches that it returns and read the `Group(1).Value` of each one.

Comment: ooohhh man this is getting a bit tough. again i am sorry for the complications. i changed match to matchcollection and the match method to matches. i am not really good at loops and am not sure how to return the Group(1).value. thank you for you cooperation and patients.

Comment: No problem.  I'll add an example of that to my answer.

Comment: your awesome man but it now will only output the last found directory and not all of them

Comment: Right.  Well, you need to output them inside the loop, otherwise the `path` variable will only store the value from the last iteration.  Alternatively, you could create a list variable, such as `Dim paths As New List(Of String)`, and then in the loop, just add the group value to the list (e.g. `paths.Add(path)`).  Then, after looping through the matches, you could loop through the list to process each one.

Comment: hmm having trouble getting the list loop to work but i will experiment with it tonight. i have to step away from the computer for a little while. Thank you again Mr. Doggart you are fantastic!

Comment: Let me know if you have any more problems. Of course I could help you much more thoroughly via CodeMentor, but I understand if that's not a possibility :)

Comment: ok i got it by adding `Dim paths As New List(Of String)` before the loop, adding `Dim path As String = m.Groups(1).Value` and `paths.Add(path)` inside the loop, and creating a new loop `For Each Path In paths` with `Dim value As String = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, paths)` and   `RichTextBox2.Text = value` inside of it

Comment: You've got it!  Nice work.  RegEx is a bit of an advanced feature, so as a beginner, I wouldn't necessarily focus on it yet, but for future reference, bear in mind that it's a very useful standard which is supported by many languages and development tools.  For instance, Microsoft's Visual Studio and SQL Server Management Studio both allow you to perform RegEx searches and replacements on your code and SQL scripts, which can save you a lot of time while coding.

Comment: that is actually really helpful sir because my next project is indexing through my companies sql for reports. you are awesome i will use what you taught me forever.